Populate Custom filed value in the chatter rather than the Name and Auto number in Chatter
I had created a Custom Object "Reviews" as a child object (Lookup) to Account So that users can give ratings for an account and display under accounts.
Whenever a review record is created it will post in Chatter as below

But I wanted to display a custom filed "Comments" rather than the auto number. How can I achieve it. I tried changing Tracking feed settings--Unchecked "All related objects" under accounts and Checked only Comments field under Review object. But it doesn't work.
